# Corda RAFT TLS V1

Tags: ssl, corda, raft

Has been changed the RAFT implementation on Corda Version 3 or it is similar to Version 2 and is not possible to disabled TLS v1?

We know Corda use TLS v1.2 but v1 is still active and we need to completely disabled. Is there a way to perform that ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There haven't been any changes for that in Corda 3.0, and it's slightly outside our control since it's managed by an external libary we use, Copycat.

I'm just curious why you need to completely disable it – the Raft notary is configured to use TLS v1.2, and you could firewall the Raft ports to only be accessible to cluster members.

Comment: Actually we can not firewalled these servers by Global Policies in our servers. Is Copycat Open Source? What version is used by Corda v3? I am thinking maybe we can disabled TLS v1.0 directly in the library code...